# fopen to createfile : Access modes Conversion

Tags: c, winapi, file-io, fopen

I want to know what are the createfile access and sharing modes that match with the following fopen access modes :

- "rb+c"
- "wb+c"

I checked for a nice table with all this information but did not find it.

Comment: Did you read the documentation for both funtions?

Comment: Yes I did letal-guitar, and it not clear to if wb+ (c ??) is GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_WRITE or GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE or something else.

Comment: @user3121023 no, `c` is a GNU C library specific extension. It's described [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen). This is what I meant by "man page".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fopen() '**c**' flag does not applicable to CreateFile(), in that it only applies a mode related to opening a file, not creating one.

For Linux, 'fopen()' the flags indicated in the question are as follows:

- **"rb+c"**
  - **r** Open file for reading. The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file.
  - **b** Strictly for compatibility with C89 and has no effect; the 'b' is ignored on all POSIX conforming systems, including Linux.
  - **+** Extends the **r** flag (above) to also allow writing to the file.
  - **c** Do not make the open operation, or subsequent read and write operations, thread cancellation points.
- **"wb+c"**
  - **w** Open file for writing. The file is created if it does not exist, otherwise the file is truncated to zero length. The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file.
  - **b** Strictly for compatibility with C89 and has no effect; the 'b' is ignored on all POSIX conforming systems, including Linux.
  - **+** Extends the **w** flag (above) to also allow reading of the file.
  - **c** Do not make the open operation, or subsequent read and write operations, thread cancellation points.

Translated to CreateFile():

- **"rb+c"**
  *dwDesiredAccess*
  `GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE`
  *dwShareMode*
  `FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE`
  *dwCreationDisposition*
  `OPEN_EXISTING`
  *dwFlagsAdAttributes*
  `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL`

```
CreateFile(
   ...,
   GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE, 
   FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
   NULL, 
   OPEN_EXISTING,
   FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
   ...
   );
```

**"wb+c"**

*dwDesiredAccess* `GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE`
    *dwShareMode* `FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE`
    *dwCreationDisposition* `TRUNCATE_EXISTING|OPEN_ALWAYS`
    *dwFlagsAdAttributes* `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL`

```
CreateFile(
   ...
   GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE, 
   FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
   NULL, 
   TRUNCATE_EXISTING|OPEN_ALWAYS,
   FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
   ...
   );
```

Comment: We can read all that on the man page. And that still doesn't tell the OP how to translate this to the corresponding `CreateFile` flags.

Comment: @Mahonri Moriancumer : How did you deduced the share mode ?

Comment: @willll, (Did I guess wrong?)  The fopen() flags in the question flags did not include an 'x' (open the file exclusively).